# Computing the range of a linear transformation over the space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

The original problem can be found [here](http://linear.ups.edu/fcla/archetype-T.html). The linear transformation is defined as: $$T: P_4 \rightarrow P_5  : T(p(x)) = (x-2)p(x) $$

The spanning set is: $$\{
x-2,\,
x^2-2x,\,
x^3-2x^2,\,
x^4-2x^3,
x^5-2x^4,
x^6-2x^5\}$$
Which is also a little confusing to me since it implies that the standard basis for $P_4$ is:
$$ \{ 1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5 \} $$
even though $ P_4 $ is the space of all polynomials of degree 4. Moving on the linked page says that a range for the linear transformation is:
$$
\{ -\frac{1}{32}x^5+1,\,
-\frac{1}{16}x^5+x,\,
-\frac{1}{8}x^5+x^2,\,
-\frac{1}{4}x^5+x^3,\,
-\frac{1}{2}x^5+x^4 \}
$$

My attempt to create a range given the spanning set is as follows. I referenced the spanning set and put it into matrix form as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0&-2 \\
-2&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&-2&1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&-2&1&0&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&-2&1&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&0&-2&1&0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I proceeded to transpose, row reduce, and take the rows as columns to create a basis for the range, however, instead of getting the range above I just got the identity matrix of size 6. The transpose, row reduce, and removing the zero rows was a strategy suggested by the book and has worked thus far. How can I create a range of a linear transformation over the space of polynomials? Is the standard basis for $P_4$ given by the textbook correct? I thought that the set had to have a term of highest order 4.

Comment: The spanning set is bad. The linked page does a bad job didactically. For the codomain it is better to take the basis $1,y,y^2,y^3, y^4, y^5$, where $y=x-2$. Then the image is clear, spanned by the last five polynomials. Taking an other basis works, but i do not want to work with it. You write: "*Attempting to solve this problem myself I took...*" Which problem is meant here?! (It is a bad idea to use awkward bases for $P_4$ and $P_5$, then show injectivity and missing surjectivity in terms of the matrice of the linear map $T:P_4\to P_5$. Why this way? Use polynomials and their properties.)

Comment: Thanks, @dan_fulea. The problem I reference is the problem of creating a range given the spanning set. I have edited the question for clarity. A "proper" answer would be much appreciated with work provided. Your answer provides some criticism of the wording the problem which is useful, however, I have no experience solving a problem in the way you described. Thus, a proper answer with work would be very much appreciated. In short, how could the problem statement and answer be better formed "didactically?"

Comment: In addition, the basis you provide is of degree 5 ($y^5$) however the transformation is from $P_4 \rightarrow P_5$. What am I missing?

Comment: I have to build sentences. First of all, i do not really like the presentation on the linked page, yes, they claim and claim, but what are they wanting to show? Then here is how i would see the story. We have a map from $P_4$, vector space over $\Bbb Q$ say of polynomials of degree $\le 4$ in $x$, i am taking $1,y,y^2,y^3,y^4$ as basis. Here $y=x-2$. It goes to $P_5$, polynomials of degree $\le 5$ in $x$. My basis for $P_5$ is $1,y,y^2,y^3,y^4$. Then the given map $T:P_4\to P_5$ has a clear range, it is spanned by  $y,y^2,y^3,y^4,y^5$. Is $T$ injective? Yes, from $yf=0$ we get $f=0$.

Comment: Is $T$ surjective? No, since $f(2)=0$ for any $f$ in the image of $T$, but the constant polynomial $1$ does not satisfy this relation. I hope there is no open issue remained.